# How are we to understand MT 6:34b in the Hebraic context?

Tags: matthew, jesus, context, sermon-on-the-mount

Mt. 6:34b "Each day has enough trouble of its own."

Comment: Is this a quote from the NIV, perhaps ?

Comment: "Don't borrow sorrow from tomorrow" because you will have your hands full with today's sorrow.

Answer (score 2):

**Which group of Israelites is Jesus speaking to in Matthew 6:[34]**, when stating : “So do not worry about tomorrow; for tomorrow will worry about itself. Each day has enough trouble of its own." ?

- This message is for **The Poor** (Who cannot always afford to buy food / beverages / clothing - Matthew 6:25-33).

In Hebraic context, we read this also in **Proverbs 15:[15]** :

> "All the days of a poor man are wretched, but he who has a cheerful heart always has a feast." ( כָּל־יְמֵ֣י עָנִ֣י רָעִ֑ים וְטֽוֹב־לֵ֜֗ב מִשְׁתֶּ֥ה תָמִֽיד )

Answer (score 0):

Here are some contexts in Matthew 6:

> 11 Give us today our daily bread. ...
> 31 So do not worry, saying, 'What shall we eat?' or 'What shall we drink?' or 'What shall we wear?' ...
> 34Therefore do not worry about tomorrow, for tomorrow will worry about itself. Each day has enough trouble of its own.

Jesus implored the Jews not to engage in daily routine worries. In the Hebrew context, it reminded them of
Exodus 16:

> 4 Then the Lord said to Moses, “I will rain down bread from heaven for you. The people are to go out each day and gather enough for **that day**. In this way I will test them and see whether they will follow my instructions.

They were also mindful of Proverbs 27:

> 1
> Do not boast about tomorrow, for you do not know what a day may bring.

Jesus wasn't encouraging laziness and irresponsibility. His point was in verse 33:

> But seek first his kingdom and his righteousness, and all these things will be given to you as well.

You would pass the test if you are concerned with God's business first.

Answer (score 0):

> Mattews 6:34 Shem Tov ben-Izaak ben-Shaprut אַל תִּדְאֲגוּ לַיּוֹם מָחָר שֶׁיּוֹם מָחָר יִדְאֲגוּ מִמֶּנּוּ דַּי לוֹ לַיּוֹם בְּצָרָתוֹ‏

Don't exceed each **day's** care limit, because **tomorrow** is enough trouble for the **day**.

We must not speculate or conjecture possible problems beyond what the light of day itself presents us with as challenges. Jesus is guiding us not to be anxious for reasons that are not within our reach to solve them